# Splitting a type-level list in GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am having a difficult time convincing GHC that certain properties
of list manipulation are true. Before I provide the code that I'm
working on, I'll give a brief example of the property I'm interested in.
Suppose we have some type-level list `xs`:

```
xs ~ '[ 'A, 'B, 'C, 'D, 'E, 'F ]
```

And we drop some of the elements and also take the same number of
elements:

```
Drop 2 xs ~ '[ 'C, 'D, 'E, 'F ]
TakeReverse 2 xs ~ '[ 'B, 'A ]
```

It should be obvious that if I apply `Drop` and `TakeReverse` 
using the successor of 2, then I can just pop the `'C` off of
`Drop 2 xs` and put it on top of `TakeReverse 2 xs`:

```
Drop 3 xs ~ '[ 'D, 'E, 'F ]
TakeReverse 3 xs ~ '[ 'C, 'B, 'A ]
```

The following code has a function named `moveRight` that attempts to
use this property. I have cut my actual code down to a somewhat small example that 
illustrates the issue and has no dependencies.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module Minimal where

import Data.Type.Equality

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Natty (n :: Nat) where
  Zy :: Natty 'Z
  Sy :: Natty n -> Natty ('S n)

data HRec (vs :: [*]) where
  HRecNil  :: HRec '[]
  HRecCons :: x -> HRec xs -> HRec (x ': xs)

data HProxy (vs :: [k]) where
  HProxyNil  :: HProxy '[]
  HProxyCons :: HProxy xs -> HProxy (x ': xs)

data Parts n rs = Parts
  { partLeft  :: HRec (Drop n rs) 
  , partRight :: HRec (TakeReverse n rs)
  , partNatty :: Natty n
  , partProxy :: HProxy rs
  }

-- The type families Drop, Take, and TakeReverse
-- are all partial.
type family Drop (n :: Nat) (xs :: [k]) :: [k] where
  Drop 'Z xs = xs
  Drop ('S n) (x ': xs) = Drop n xs

type family Take (n :: Nat) (xs :: [k]) :: [k] where
  Take 'Z xs = '[]
  Take ('S n) (x ': xs) = x ': Take n xs

type family TakeReverse (n :: Nat) (xs :: [k]) :: [k] where
  TakeReverse n xs = TakeReverseHelper '[] n xs

type family TakeReverseHelper (ys :: [k]) (n :: Nat) (xs :: [k]) :: [k] where
  TakeReverseHelper res 'Z xs = res
  TakeReverseHelper res ('S n) (x ': xs) = TakeReverseHelper (x ': res) n xs

moveRight :: Parts n rs -> Parts (S n) rs
moveRight (Parts pleft@(HRecCons pleftHead _) pright natty proxy) = 
  case dropOneProof natty proxy of
    Refl -> Parts (dropOne pleft) (HRecCons pleftHead pright) (Sy natty) proxy

dropOneProof :: Natty n -> HProxy rs -> (Drop ('S n) rs :~: Drop ('S 'Z) (Drop n rs))
dropOneProof Zy _ = Refl
dropOneProof (Sy n) (HProxyCons rs) = case dropOneProof n rs of
  Refl -> Refl

dropOne :: HRec rs -> HRec (Drop ('S 'Z) rs)
dropOne (HRecCons _ rs) = rs
```

This code does not compile because of `moveRight`. Basically, I'm able to
prove that dropping an additional element from the left side gives it 
the right type, but I can't show that adding this element to the right 
side makes it have the right type.

I'm really open to any changes. I'm fine with changing the type families,
introducing extra witnesses, etc., as long as `moveRight` becomes 
possible to write.

If I need to further clarify what I am trying to do, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @dfeuer You are correct. I've changed it.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to clarify, yes. And I suspect you will need to use type families differently. I suspect it may help to "warm up" by using length-indexed heterogeneous lists and splitting them with `Fin` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your representation is that you try to make the position of the split explicit, but don't enforce the validity of the position index.

As it is currently `moveRight :: Parts n rs -> Parts (S n) rs` can't be implemented, because if `n` is out of bounds, `Take` and the other type family applications cannot reduce and therefore no value can be given in the result.

There are many ways to solve this issue. The simplest is to make the types in the left and right parts of the context explicit:

```
type HZipper xs ys = (HRec xs, HRec ys)

moveRight :: HZipper xs (y ': ys) -> HZipper (y ': xs) ys
moveRight'(xs, HCons y ys) = (HCons y xs, ys)
```

This is actually just as strong representatation as your original `Parts`. provided that we enforce the bounds on the `n` index there. That's because both types indicate the whole list and the exact position of the split. From `HZipper xs ys`, the original type list can be computed as `Reverse xs ++ ys` with the appropriate `++` and `Reverse` type families. This is sometimes less convenient, but on the up side `HZipper` has much simpler internals.

Alternatively, you can hide the position of split existentially. In any case, this requires proof writing for `moveRight`:

```
import Data.Type.Equality
import Data.Proxy

data HRec vs where
  HNil  :: HRec '[]
  HCons :: x -> HRec xs -> HRec (x ': xs)

type family (++) xs ys where
  '[] ++ ys = ys
  (x ': xs) ++ ys = x ': (xs ++ ys)

type family Reverse xs where
  Reverse '[] = '[]
  Reverse (x ': xs) = Reverse xs ++ '[x]

data HZipper xs where
  HZipper :: HRec ys -> HRec zs -> HZipper (Reverse ys ++ zs)

hcat :: HRec xs -> HRec ys -> HRec (xs ++ ys)
hcat HNil         ys = ys
hcat (HCons x xs) ys = HCons x (hcat xs ys)

hreverse :: HRec xs -> HRec (Reverse xs)
hreverse HNil         = HNil
hreverse (HCons x xs) = hreverse xs `hcat` (HCons x HNil)

catAssoc :: HRec xs -> Proxy ys -> Proxy zs -> (xs ++ (ys ++ zs)) :~: ((xs ++ ys) ++ zs)
catAssoc HNil xs ys = Refl
catAssoc (HCons x xs) ys zs = case catAssoc xs ys zs of
  Refl -> Refl

moveRight :: HZipper xs -> HZipper xs
moveRight (HZipper ls HNil) = HZipper ls HNil
moveRight (HZipper ls (HCons (x :: x) (xs :: HRec xs))) =
  case catAssoc (hreverse ls) (Proxy :: Proxy '[x]) (Proxy :: Proxy xs) of
    Refl -> HZipper (HCons x ls) xs
```

There's a third possibility, namely adding an existential bounds check inside the original `Parts`, or having `moveRight :: InBounds (S n) rs -> Parts n rs -> Parts (S n) rs`, where `InBounds` is a proof of inbounds-ness. Or we could have `InBounds (S n) rs => ...` with `InBounds` a type family returning a class constraint. This approach would also require quite a bit of proof-writing though.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the issue I was having. Your first suggestion ended up being completely sufficient for what I was doing and simplified things considerably.